# Check whether a number falls within 32/bit range in ADD operation is ARM

Tags: arm, branch, flags, carryflag

How can I check whether the NBC number falls within 32-bit range after an operation
ADD RO,RO,R1, LSL#1

I have read that it can be tested with a C flag which determines whether there is an overflow in such operation but I am not entirely sure how to set the "if" condition, e.g. if there has been overflow I should remove the value from the register and write something else inside it.

Comment: What's an "NBC number"?

Comment: Is it known that the high bit of R1 is clear, i.e. that the shift will not overflow by itself?  If so, then yes, the carry flag is set if the addition overflows unsigned, assuming you use `adds` to set flags.  In ARM state, all instructions can be made conditional, so you could simply `adds r0, r0, r1, lsl #1 ; movcs r0, #1234` to use the value 1234 if there was an overflow.

Comment: signed or unsigned overflow?